# Web Audio API not playing sound sample on device, but works in browser

Tags: ios, audio, ionic-framework, web-audio-api

I have an Ionic app that is a metronome. Using Web Audio API I have made everything work using the oscillator feature, but when switching to use a wav file no audio is playing on a real device (iPhone).

When testing in the browser using Ionic Serve (chrome) the audio plays fine.

Here is what I have:

```
function snare(e) {
    var audioSource = 'assets/audio/snare1.wav';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', audioSource, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // Decode asynchronously
    request.onload = function() {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(theBuffer) {
            buffer = theBuffer;
            playSound(buffer);
        });
    }
    request.send();
}

function playSound(buffer) {
    var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

The audio sample is in www/assets/audio.

Any ideas where this could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I believe iOS devices require a user-gesture of some sort to allow playing of audio.

Comment: I usually point people to <https://gist.github.com/laziel/7aefabe99ee57b16081c> to solve this. Basically, you need to call `start` on the `AudioBufferSourceNode` from a touch handler to "unblock" the `AudioContext`.

Answer (score 0):

It's July 2017, iOS 10.3.2 and we're still finding this issue on Safari on iPhones. Interestingly Safari on a MacBook is fine.
@Raymond Toy's general observation still appears to be true. But @padenot's approach (via https://gist.github.com/laziel/7aefabe99ee57b16081c) did not work for me in a situation where I wanted to play a sound in response to some external event/trigger.

Using the original poster's code, I've had some success with this

```
var buffer; // added to make it work with OP's code

// keep the original function snare()

function playSound() { // dropped the argument for simplicity.
   var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
   source.buffer = buffer;
   source.connect(audioContext.destination);
   source.start(0);
}

function triggerSound() {

    function playSoundIos(event) {
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', playSoundIos);
        playSound();
    }

    if (/iPad|iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', playSoundIos);
    }
    else { // Android etc. or Safari, but not on iPhone 
        playSound();
    }
}
```

Now calling `triggerSound()` will produce the sound immediately on Android and will produce the sound on iOS after the browser page has been touched.

Still not ideal, but better than no sound at all...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in current iOS (15). I tried to play base64 encoded binary data which worked in all browsers, but not on iOS.

Finally reordering of the statements solved my issue:

```
let buffer = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
let context = new AudioContext();

// these lines were within "play()" before
audioSource = context.createBufferSource();
audioSource.connect(context.destination);
audioSource.start(0);
// ---

context.decodeAudioData(buffer.buffer, play, (e) => {
    console.warn("error decoding audio", e)
});

function play(audioBuffer) {
    audioSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
}
```

Also see this [commit in my project](https://github.com/asterics/AsTeRICS-Grid/commit/4170f2d9ed676c5e085eabbb84a7c98d5f79761a).

I assume that calling `audioSource.start(0)` within the `play()` method was somehow too late because it's within a callback after `context.decodeAudioData()` and therefore maybe "too far away" from a user interaction for the standards of iOS.